# Embed Angularjs fragments in non-angular pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is it possible to create fragements/partial pages with `angularjs`, and embed them into any `html` page that is not using angularjs?

Assume an existing page where the div `some_box` is dynamically filled with a html fragment generated by `js`:

```
<html>
<body>
 <static stuff...>
 <div id="some_box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to replace the div box with angularjs generated content, but without having to add angular explicit to that existing page.

What are my chances? `IFrame`? Or could I do better?

Comment: Where/how do you intend to host and reference your angular code?

Comment: Everything will be hosted locally, eg a webserver like `tomcat`.

Comment: Yes, but you need to do something in this html page in order to reference your code, right?

Comment: Yes there actually is some simple `javascript` that calls an `url` and replaces the `some_box` div with the content returned. But at the moment this is a `php` application that serves the part for `some_box`. I'd like to create the dynamic content instead by anguljar in future.